# TIdHTTPServer raise EThread error 6 when activating it in my DUnit test

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, indy10, dunit

I need a local HTTP server for my unit test.

When I try to activate TIdHTTPServer at `SetUp`, it fails with EThread message:

> "Thread Error: descriptor not valid (6)"

This is how I initialize it:

```
type
  TestMyUnit = class(TTestCase)
...
procedure TestMyUnit.SetUp;
begin
  FServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
  FServer.OnCommandGet := HTTPServerCommandGet;
  FServer.Active := True;   // <---- This will cause error
end;
```

Maybe there are some restrictions using Indy's TIdHTTPServer with DUnit framework?

- Delphi 2010
- Indy 10

Exception was thrown somewhere after this line in `TIdListenerThread.Run` proc (IdCustomTCPServer unit)

```
LIOHandler := Server.IOHandler.Accept(Binding, Self, LYarn);
```

However, I can't trace it deeper, I don't know why.

Comment: I have to ask this... Have you tried running the executable on a different machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I have my own DPK with self-designed components (used by this unit-test), and there was 1 unit with references to Indy. After I have rebuild that package, the compiler proposed me to add some new DCCReference to Indy components. After I reinstalled my package, that error in unit-test has gone.

I can't imagine the cause-and-effect relations, but now it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to allow your DUnit executable to open the port in your firewall setup... Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules.

Usually windows will ask you the first time the executable tries to open the port, but I would check that there is a rule in there anyway.

**Edit:**

Just add a bit more information, the error "Descriptor not valid" looks like a winsock error, and could be because your code can't open the port. It could be because it is blocked at the firewall (as I meantioned above) or it could be that you have another program that has that port opened... Like IIS perhaps? I would choose a port above 1024 somewhere and set your web server to use that (and obviously your client).

**Edit 2:**

My code for setting up my TIdHttpServer is:

```
FServer := TIdHttpServer.Create(nil);
FServer.DefaultPort := 7777;
FServer.AutoStartSession := True;
FServer.OnCommandGet := ServerCommandGet;
FServer.OnCreatePostStream := ServerCreatePostStream;

FServer.Active := True;
```

Comment: no change after disabling firewall and setting `DefaultPort` to 10080

Comment: Seems I have found the problem. I have my own DPK with self-designed components (used by this unit-test), and there was 1 unit with references to Indy. After I have rebuild that package, the compiler proposed me to add some new DCCReference to Indy. After I reinstalled my package, that error has gone. How do you think, should I add this as answer or it is better check your answer as correct? My situation is not very common I think.

Comment: I would add an answer of your own explaining what you did, and after 24 hours, accept it :)